# Refactoring Web App code when API gets added later

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2, gae-python27

I have a Web Application for which we are adding an API now.

I am looking for best practices to keep in mind while working on this.

I am considering these factors:

- DRY: Avoid redundancy (to the extent possible).
  Take for example, a part of the code which handles a form submission. 
  There are some parts which are applicable for only Web Form submission but not relevant to the equivalent API Post call.  I am thinking of modularizing the common code behind this Post handlers. I must add that the handler classes for Web Form and API are different. I am creating a third class which will have the common methods. This third class would be inherited by the two handler classes (along with their other base classes, multiple-inheritance).
- Should I refactor the code such that the Web Form 'Post' handler method in turn calls the API Post method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the specifics of this will vary significantly on a case by case basis, but I did something like this recently, and I'll share what I came up with.

This is how I organized my handlers so I don't repeat myself:

```
class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler)
    class ApiHandler(MyHandler):
        class Ajax(ApiHandler): # Ajax calls on my website
        class V0(ApiHandler): # V0 of my REST API for third parties
    class WebHandler(MyHandler):
        class HomePage(WebHandler):
        class OtherPage(WebHandler):
```

I added a lot of utility methods that can be used by subclasses.  For example, `MyHandler` has a `write_json` method because that is used in a lot of places, and `ApiHandler` has a `process_json` method because that is used only by APIs.

I think it is a bad idea to avoid repeating yourself by having one post method call another post method.  Instead, I think it would keep your code cleaner to do the refactoring at the model level.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. 
Were you using webapp2 for API handlers? Weren't you using Endpoints?

Comment: I used webapp2.  I think I took a look at endpoints but it was so easy to do with webapp2 that I didn't want to spend the time learning something new.  I think endpoints is more for people who don't already have an app engine app (but I could be wrong).